# Can not open any file with default applications?

Tags: files

When I double click on any file it does nothing.

To open a file I need to open an application from the application menu and drag and drop the file on the application.

Where is the problem?

Comment: What file manager/desktop environment are you using?

Comment: I'm using Nautilus file manager. And xfce desktop environment.